# Having both [Next] and [NewLine] keys in Android softinput (on-screen keyboard)

Tags: android, xamarin.android, soft-input-panel

I have designed a wizard form in the **Android** using Xamarin, and in that form I have added a *multi-line EditText*. In run-time when I focus on the multi-line EditText the on-screen Keyboard (SoftInput) **appears with just new-line key**.

How can I have **both** new-line key and action "Next" (or "Done") key in my soft-input **at the same time**? Does any one have any experience in having the **both** keys in Android on-screen keyboard at once?

Also, please do not redirect me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014219/multiline-edittext-with-done-softinput-action-label-on-2-3). It is not related to my problem. ;)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: it would appear you can only customize the 'key' when the EditText is single line: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789533/how-to-add-next-on-android-keyboard

Comment: Unfortunately yes @quidproquo. I've been searching a lot, and you are correct. But again, whats wrong with this idea, when you want the multi-line EditText with full **multi-line capabilities** and the **Next button** on the keyboard at once? Specifically when you ***do not*** want to make your screen crowded with and <android:Button... /> of  'Next' or 'Finish'!

Comment: Also, I have found [this sample code](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615) for creating custom soft keyboard, by defining each and every key on it. I am not sure if I can get my answer in this solution but I am still searching for better ideas.